# S3 Access error with Emr with Spark 2.4.4 and Scala

Tags: amazon-emr

I am trying to access an S3 file in Spark on EMR using Scala code and getting the below error

EMR Configuration :

[EMR Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXDIS.png)

**Scala Code**

```
    val hadoopConf = sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
    if (baseDirectory.startsWith("s3:")) {
      hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
      hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", jobProperties.getAs[String](S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID))
      hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", jobProperties.getAs[String](S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
    }
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI(baseDirectory), hadoopConf)
```

**ERROR**

```
20/03/28 15:18:06 ERROR Client: Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: s3n://r10x-tlog/occ/gzip/test_$folder$
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.processException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.processException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:427)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.handleException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:411)
        at
```

I have checked the Spark And Hadoop jars
[Hadoop Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zQZZ.png)

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of s3n please use **s3**. s3a and s3n is not supported in EMR.
Also make sure your EMR_IAM_Role has access to that s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [EMRFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-fs.html) instead of s3a or s3n because it's the native implementation to use S3 as FS.

using EMRFS, you don't need to use credentials to use S3. You would just need to grant the permission to [EMR_EC2_DefaultRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-iam-roles.html)

Answer (score 0):

just give the necessary permissions for list-objects and get-object to your access key and you are good to go.